# How to set back color on mouse leave in menu item.?

Tags: c#, winforms, menu

A **menu tool strip** is used in **WinForm** application. On checking menu option, it opens sub menus. *When mouse enters in the boundary of sub menu the back color is change to green. Now, I want to change this color to red, when mouse leave the boundary of sub-menu.*
Any suggestions ?

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    SolidBrush brush;
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(this.Bounds.Width - 20, 2, 16, 17);

    // If click on Del(Close Icon)
    if (bOnDel)
    {
        brush = new SolidBrush(Color.LightBlue);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, r);
        brush.Color = Color.Blue;
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(brush, 1), r);
    }
    // If didn't click on Del(Close Icone)
    if (!bOnDel)
    {

        brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Transparent));
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, r);
        brush.Color = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Transparent);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(brush, 1), r);
    }

    //Code for Drawing Cross Lines

    brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Gray);
    Rectangle rCross = new Rectangle(this.Bounds.Width - 15, 8, 6, 6);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(brush, 2), new Point(rCross.Right, rCross.Top), new Point(rCross.Left, rCross.Bottom));
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(brush, 2), new Point(rCross.Left, rCross.Top), new Point(rCross.Right, rCross.Bottom));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [MouseLeave event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.mouseleave%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for the [ToolStripMenuItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5b29tk4%28v=vs.100%29) to change the [BackColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.backcolor%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Property:

```
private void yourToolStripMenuItem_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

---

You can look into using the [MouseMove Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.mousemove%28v=vs.100%29), make sure that your rectangle is declared outside of the Paint Event and Invalidate the Control using the Rectangle as the region. Here is an example base on your code, I declared a boolean entered and rectangle r in the beginning of the Class. You would put any highlight changes in your paint event. This is more like what I think you want.

```
public partial class CustomControl1 : ToolStripMenuItem 
{
    Rectangle r;
    bool entered;

    public CustomControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        SolidBrush brush;
        r = new Rectangle(this.Bounds.Width - 20, 2, 16, 17);

        // If MouseEnter Del(Close Icon)
        if (entered)
        {
            brush = new SolidBrush(Color.LightBlue);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, r);
            brush.Color = Color.Blue;
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(brush, 1), r);
        }
        // If Mouse Not Entered Del(Close Icone)
        if (!entered)
        {

            brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Transparent));
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, r);
            brush.Color = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Transparent);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(brush, 1), r);
        }

        //Code for Drawing Cross Lines

        brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Gray);
        Rectangle rCross = new Rectangle(this.Bounds.Width - 15, 8, 6, 6);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(brush, 2), new Point(rCross.Right, rCross.Top), new Point(rCross.Left, rCross.Bottom));
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(brush, 2), new Point(rCross.Left, rCross.Top), new Point(rCross.Right, rCross.Bottom));
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);

        if (r.Contains(e.X, e.Y) && !entered)
        {
            entered = true;
            Invalidate(r);
        }
        else if (!r.Contains(e.X, e.Y) && entered)
        {
            entered = false;
            Invalidate(r);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is much accurate. But, I've something more to do. Actually, On sub-menu Item I have created a rectangle with x as a representation of close button. So, I've changed that rectangle back color to blue (highlight) on mouseover. Now, I need to change that color to default(previous). How can I do this? Code is attached below:

Comment: @Itz.Irshad I am, I am trying to figure out what you are doing. are you trying to create your own menu's, because you are painting your rectangle on the Form, not the Menu. What style of form is this, is it border set to none?

Comment: Firstly, thanks for attention. and Secondly sorry for ambiguity. Let me clear the things: I am creating a rectangle within menu items to give the user facility to delete the highlighted item from menu. So, I need to change the color of that run-time created rectangle with cross button. I mean, on mouseover it'll be highlighted and on mouse leave it'll be as in previous state. I hope you got my point. Don't you ?

Comment: @Itz.Irshad Your OnPaint event as given is painting on the Form, not the Menu Item unless you are creating a custom control. I will give you an example based on what you posted.